# Evaluate function using Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\int \frac{z^2 + z^7}{(z-e/3)^3} \, dz $$ where $\Gamma$ is a rectangular path traversed in the counterclockwise direction with vertices $1, 2i,−1,−2i.$  So I have noticed there is a singularity at $e/3.$ which also lies within the rectangle defined. I'm not sure what the next step is as substituting $e/3$ into the function gives an undefined value.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the residue at a pole of order $>1$?

Comment: No sorry, I did wonder if i was missing something in order to solve this problem.

Comment: It's not a rectangle; it's a rhombus. In a rectangle there is a right angle at every one of the four vertices. A rhombus is a quadrilateral in which all for sides have the same length, and is consequently a parallelogram, but most parallelograms are not rhombi.

Comment: Not all sides have the same length though? Width of 2 and height of 4.

Comment: Normally if you write $\text{“}[\,\ldots\,]\text{ where } \Gamma \text{ is } [\,\ldots\,]\text{''},$ it would follow an expression in which $\text{“}\Gamma\text{''}$ appears. You could just write $$ \int_\Gamma \frac{z^2 + z^7}{(z-e/3)^3} \,dx $$

Comment: @AdamJones : All four sides have the same length. The first goes from $1$ to $2i,$ the second from $2i$ to $-1,$ and so on. The length of the first side is $\sqrt 5,$ and so is the second, and so are the other two.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles

Comment: yes sorry you are right, i drew my diagram wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z)=z^2+z^7$. Then, according to Cauchy's integral formula, your integral is equal to$$\frac{2!}{2\pi i}f''\left(\frac e3\right)=-\frac i\pi\times\left(2+\frac{14e^5}{81}\right).$$

Comment: I understand everything you've done there except from where (1/e) came from if you could explain this that would be great, thank you.

Comment: @AdamJones What I did was to apply the equality$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}$$with $n=2$ and $a=\frac1e$.

Comment: I understand the formula used but I can't see where the value $(1/e)$ came about. Is it to do with the zero of the denominator being at $z= (e/3)$?

Comment: @AdamJones I'm sorry. I made several mistakes in my computation. I suppose that it is correct now.

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate your patience with the explanations.